# Fighting with styling in ListFragment (grey text that I can only override in xml)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Building an app using `android.support.v4.app`, targeting API level 8. Everything's working as planned minus some styling issues I can't seem to figure out.

I'm using `ListFragments` with other elements in the layout outside of the `ListView` (header, etc.) but it seems that the list items are taking some of weird styling or overlay, unless I modify the layout of the list item in XML (changing it in code changes the shade of grey, but does not actually display the color.

Sample project exhibiting behavior:
[REDACTED]

Comment: The same type of thing is happening with the list items backgrounds as well. The colors seem like there's something turning them grayscale...The way around it, it seems, is for me to `setBackgroundResource` with a drawable that just has the color I actually want to show up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...knew it was something silly.

Make sure you give `getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor)` instead of just `R.color.mycolor` when setting color from code.